# Drawing a range column chart using DOT language or java or similar?

Tags: java, charts, graphviz

I want to draw a range column chart for my data, something similar to [this](http://www.jqchart.com/jquery/chart/ChartTypes/RangeColumnChart).
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GraphViz isn't suitable for this sort of chart - it draws graphs of the "nodes and edges" type, rather than this sort of style.

It looks like the "range column" chart is essentially a stacked bar chart with four elements in each stack, with the bottom element and third element drawn without borders and with a transparent fill. So, I'd suggest trying to use a conventional graphing library that gives enough flexibility of control over bar charts to produce what you want.